# Add related products in Mobile Shoppe Magento theme

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I try to add more products on the product page. but it seem like the theme I have chosen called "Mobile shoppe" does not support that feature. Is it any more like andvänt this theme that can direct me how to do.

In html code it says how it can give no clue to someone who is good at magento code.

```
    <div class="no-display"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="1" 
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field"
          value="">
     </div>
```

If I try to make it visible to display only one ID.

Comment: Is Andvant a theme? If so, make a link to it! Where did you get the HTML code from? What page, front-end or admin? Do you want to display only one ID? It's not clear to me.